# PIVOT table in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have data like this :

```
end date    billing
30-NOV-16   0
31-DEC-16   0
31-JAN-17   0
28-FEB-17   208200
31-MAR-17   362950
```

and when I run this query :

```
 SELECT *
   FROM
     (SELECT  


        ps.end_date end_date

     ,  ps.itd_gross_billing  billing 

FROM  project_summary_v  ps 
JOIN  projects_dtl  pd ON ps.project_id=pd.project_id 
JOIN  periods_dim xpd ON ps.end_date=xpd.end_date 
WHERE  pd.project_number=100 

FETCH FIRST 6 rows only
      )
   PIVOT
     (
             max(billing)                
             FOR end_date in ( '31-OCT-16' 
,'30-NOV-16'
,'31-DEC-16'
,'31-JAN-17'
,'28-FEB-17'
,'31-MAR-17' )
      );
```

I get the following output

```
   31-OCT-16  30-NOV-16 31-DEC-16  31-JAN-17    28-FEB-17   31-MAR-17
     0         0          0          0           208200     362950
```

All good so far. But when I have few more columns data,

```
   end date    billing   pd_data  mn_data
    31-OCT-16   0           10      1
    30-NOV-16   0          100      2
    31-DEC-16   0          200      3
    31-JAN-17   0          90       4
    28-FEB-17   208200     30       5
    31-MAR-17   362950     50       6
```

How to transpose this table ? Also if the end date is dynamic  ( as of now I have hard coded )- What should be the query inside the in ( ) .

Output should be something like this :

```
           31-OCT-16  30-NOV-16 31-DEC-16  31-JAN-17    28-FEB-17   31-MAR-17
billing     0          0          0          0           208200     362950
pd_data     10        100        200         90          30          50
mn_data      1         2          3           4           5           6
```

Comment: "How to transpose this table" - you'd have to say what you want the result to look like. As for the second part, you can't make it completely dynamic, or use a query in the `in()` part, you either have to use PL/SQL and dynamic SQL or an XML pivot. You could potentially show the n most recent values as columns but then then headers become an issue. So again, depends what you want it to look like, to some extent. (Also, is your column actually dates or strings? You are either using the wrong data  type or relying on NLS settings for implicit conversion...)

Comment: edited my post @Alex

Comment: What is the big picture here? If this is for a report, and you use some reporting application for that, the reporting application may have much better tools for this kind of pivoting than what you can do by hand in SQL (or using PL/SQL), especially if you are not an advanced PL/SQL or XML programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the below query would work. I have separated the queries to pivot. Hope this helps.

```
SELECT   *
  FROM
    (SELECT   ps.end_date end_date ,
        ps.itd_gross_billing billing
      FROM project_summary_v ps
      JOIN projects_dtl pd
      ON ps.project_id=pd.project_id
      JOIN periods_dim xpd
      ON ps.end_date         =xpd.end_date
      WHERE pd.project_number=100
    FETCH FIRST 6 rows only
    ) pivot( MAX(billing) FOR end_date IN ( '31-OCT-16' ,'30-NOV-16' ,'31-DEC-16' ,'31-JAN-17' ,'28-FEB-17' ,'31-MAR-17' ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT   *
  FROM
    (SELECT   ps.end_date end_date ,
        ps.pd_data pd_data
      FROM project_summary_v ps
      JOIN projects_dtl pd
      ON ps.project_id=pd.project_id
      JOIN periods_dim xpd
      ON ps.end_date         =xpd.end_date
      WHERE pd.project_number=100
    FETCH FIRST 6 rows only
    ) pivot( MAX(pd_data) FOR end_date IN ( '31-OCT-16' ,'30-NOV-16' ,'31-DEC-16' ,'31-JAN-17' ,'28-FEB-17' ,'31-MAR-17' ) )
UNION ALL
SELECT   *
  FROM
    (SELECT   ps.end_date end_date ,
        ps.mn_data mn_data
      FROM project_summary_v ps
      JOIN projects_dtl pd
      ON ps.project_id=pd.project_id
      JOIN periods_dim xpd
      ON ps.end_date         =xpd.end_date
      WHERE pd.project_number=100
    FETCH FIRST 6 rows only
    ) pivot( MAX(mn_data) FOR end_date IN ( '31-OCT-16' ,'30-NOV-16' ,'31-DEC-16' ,'31-JAN-17' ,'28-FEB-17' ,'31-MAR-17' ) )
```